# HTTPS images not displaying on my localhost but going to the link shows the image

Tags: html, image, https, localhost

My browser is session authenticated with a website.

I am using their API to pull down images from the site so I can display them on my page.

Visiting that image url displays the image, putting it in an img tag does not:

```
<img src = "https://files.something.com/123123" />><!-- this doesn't show -->
<a href = "https://files.something.com/123123">arse</a><!-- this works -->
```

Any ideas on why? and how I might overcome it?

If I put in http for the link, it redirects to https any way.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things worth bearing in mind here:

- Your host is automatically redirecting to https.  Is this deliberate?
- I suspect that you're seeing coming up against cross-domain security, or that your server is actively refusing it.

To trouble-shoot: you'll want to find out what response you're getting from your images.

Open up either the 'NET' tab in Firebug, or 'Network' in Chrome Developer Tools and watch the page-load.  I suspect you're going to see those images come through red with an error number.  Once you've got that it's very easy to trouble-shoot why the server's refusing to serve the images.

Comment: lol I use IE10. but thanks, yes it is cross-domain security.. if you put an iframe in the page it seems to require to log in again, that's because the parent window doesn't have access to the session cookie set by the website I am calling from. Ahh b00-larks! There be no way round this bar-steward.